# Why is pacman-key trying to download the public key for the Pacman Keyring Master Key?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

When running `sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys` I get the following message:

> gpg: public key of ultimately trusted key XXXXXX not found

I could find only one reference to this key (`sudo locate` found nothing):

```
$ sudo grep -r XXXXXX /etc/
/etc/pacman.d/gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/XXXXXX.rev:      XXXXXX
```

Having a look inside it seems this is the revocation certificate of some auto-generated key which only my machine knows about. What am I supposed to do now to make `pacman-key` sane?

---

This also seems to be affecting the "checking keys in keyring" and "checking package integrity" phases of `pacman -Syu`, to the extent that a full core is 100% occupied with `gpg` or `gpg2` indefinitely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/1492/action-required-pacman-keyring-reset) plus [this](https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=30524.0) seem to have worked:

```
$ sudo rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
$ sudo pacman-key --init
$ sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
$ sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
```